# No. of orders placed by customer in order and customer grid

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, customer, grid

I want to display the total no. of orders placed by the customer in the order and customer grid. This will help me identify the type of customer.

### Grid.php

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $sql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
    . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o, customer_entity AS e'
    . ' WHERE o.customer_id=e.entity_id' ;
    $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 
    $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$expr));


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}    
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
        $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total No. of Orders'),
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '40px',
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
        'type'  => 'number',
        'sortable' => true,
    ));
 }
```

This shows me the total no. of orders placed and not customer wise.

How can I show the no. of orders customer wise in the order as well as customer grid ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below code.
**Grid.php**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $select = $readAdapter->select()
            ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
            ->columns(array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'))
    )->group('customer_id');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$select.')')),
        'main_table.customer_id = orders_count.customer_id',
        array('orders_count.orders_count')
    );
    $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}    
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
        $this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total No. of Orders'),
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '40px',
        'index'     => 'orders_count',
        'type'  => 'number',
        'sortable' => true,
    ));
 }
```

To add orders count to **Customer Grid**,
add below code in your `_prepareCollection()` function before you set collection on line `$this->setCollection($collection);`

```
$readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$select = $readAdapter->select()
            ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
            ->columns(array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'))
    )->group('customer_id');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$select.')')),
        'e.entity_id = orders_count.customer_id',
        array('orders_count.orders_count')
    );
$collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
```

And add your column just the same with `filter_condition_callback`,

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total No. of Orders'),
    'align'     => 'left',
    'width'     => '40px',
    'index'     => 'orders_count',
    'type'  => 'number',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersCountFilterCallBack'),
    'sortable' => false,
));
```

And Create a function in the same file,

```
protected function _ordersCountFilterCallBack($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {return $this;}
    $from = ($value['from']) ? $value['from']: 0;
    $to = ($value['to']) ? $value['to'] : 999999;
    $collection->getSelect()->where("orders_count.orders_count >= $from AND  orders_count.orders_count <= $to");
    return $this;
}
```

**NOTE** : I have disable sorting for this field because I did not get time for it. You can try it by Your self or I will update once I get time for it.

Comment: I am not able to filter it according to the count. It is filterable only according to the customer_id.  How can this be rectified ?

Comment: @RajatAgarwal, Updated answer which will work with filter and sorting.

Comment: One last question sir.. How can I display the same in the customer grid ?

Comment: Its working fine.. but I am not able to filter the field

Comment: How can I make this field filterable in customer grid ? @JaiminSutariya

Comment: @RajatAgarwal, Please check updated answer.