# Display number of orders in customer grid

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, customer-grid

I want to display the total of order for each customer, in the customer grid (Back Office).

Currently, I succeed to display the total, only if there is at least 1 order.

In _prepareCollection() :

```
$readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$select = $readAdapter->select()
    ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
    ->columns(array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'))
        )->group('customer_id');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$select.')')),
    'e.entity_id = orders_count.customer_id',
    array('orders_count.orders_count')
);
$collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

In _prepareColumns(), I added the custom column :

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total nb of orders'),
    'width'     => '40px',
    'index'     => 'orders_count',
    'type'      => 'number',
    'sortable'  => false,
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_ordersCountFilterCallBack')
));
```

I can force the displaying of 0 by add 'default' => '0' in my column but it's not that I want : In my **_ordersCountFilterCallBack** function, I want to be allow to filter orders_count.orders_count == 0 and not orders_count.orders_count IS NULL.

Any idea ?

Comment: You copied some code from this post but not all. Please follow all the steps it should work https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162903/no-of-orders-placed-by-customer-in-order-and-customer-grid

Comment: Which step did not I follow ?

Comment: The only line I didn't add is $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count'); because I don't know this purpose and with this line ou without, the result is the same for me.

Comment: did you create `_ordersCountFilterCallBack` function?

Comment: Yes and the filtrer work for all orders_count.orders_count >=1. But on the grid, that not display '0' for customer wihtout order and on my filter, I have to handle "orders_count.orders_count IS NULL" instead of "orders_count.orders_count == 0 ". :/

Comment: please add `$collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count'); ` this line before collection and check

Comment: As say before, add $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count'); change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

```
$select = $readAdapter->select()
    ->from('sales_flat_order_grid')
    ->columns(array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('IFNULL(COUNT(*),0)'))
        )->group('customer_id');
```

I have not tested it but it should work.

Comment: That seems logic, but that not works for me :(